# Help with boot problems (/dev/nvme0n1p2 partition)

Tags: boot, partitioning, initramfs, fsck

Whenever I try to boot into ubuntu now I get this error:

/init: line 872: logsave: The Text file is busy
The root filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p2 requires a manual fsck

and then it displays the initramfs command line.

When i try fsck /dev/nvme0n1p it says:

`/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, <a big number> files, <another number> blocks`

I have watched almost every video on how to fix similar problems and my results look nothing like the ones in the videos. Also whenever I try the reboot command it does nothing.

I have also tried booting from a usb and I get the exact same error! Please help!

Comment: Maybe a corrupted initrd, try booting an older kernel (under the grub/advanced) to get a different initrd.  If that works, you can mkinitramrfs on the other one.

Comment: I tried it and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a corrupted initrd, try booting an older kernel (under the grub/advanced) to get a different initrd. If that works, you can mkinitramrfs on the other one.